# Restricting overall number of characters within multiple groups

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to match the following:

Five uppercase characters, followed by an optional decimal (up to ten digits including `,`), followed by free text, and all of this can have up to 40 characters.

I ended up with the following:
`^([A-Z]{5}(\d*,\d{1,})?.*)$`
which somewhat matches my pattern, but I'm having issues restricting the number of characters of my decimal (max 10) and the total number of characters (max 40).

I've been looking at lookaheads, but I'm doing it wrong since it's not working.
For my decimal: `(?=.{0,10}(\d*,\d{1,}))`

Comment: Did any of the solutions work out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option might be using 2 positive lookaheads, one asserting the total number of chars and the other asserting 10 digits including the comma matching only that numeric format right after the 5 uppercase chars.

```
^[A-Z]{5}(?=.{0,35}$)(?:(?=[,\d]{1,10}(?![,\d]))\d+(?:,\d+)?(?![\d,]))?(?!\d).*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]{5}` Match 5 uppercase chars A-Z
- `(?=.{0,35}$)` Assert a max of 35 chars following till the end of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?=[,\d]{1,10}(?![,\d]))` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right are 1-10 times a digit or a comma not directly followed by a digit or comma
  - `\d+(?:,\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
  - `(?![\d,])` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not a digit or comma
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `(?!\d)` Negative lookahead, assert not a digit to the right
- `.*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o5c3mL/1)

Comment: This works, however, I was wondering if there is a shorter way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(?=.{0,40})^([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{0,10}.{0,35})$
```